# show hide div with radio box using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four `radio box` like this:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="" name="display" style="">Home</input>
<input type="radio" value="" name="display" style="">Featured</input>
<input type="radio" value="" name="display" style="">Normal</input>
<input type="radio" value="" name="display" style="">Draft</input>
```

Now i have Three `DIV` for Featured, Normal, Draft radio box with `display:none` like this:

```
<div id="Featured" style="display:none">Featured desc</div>
<div id="Normal" style="display:none">Normal desc</div>
<div id="Draft" style="display:none">Draft desc</div>
```

Now, i need to after `click/selected` each radio button show div with same `id` Using jQuery.

`NOTE: for Home radio box i dont need to any div.`

Comment: P.s. I'm sure you got a downvote because you did not even imply that you've tried anything yet.  You have to show what you've tried for us to help you.  We don't just write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that inputs are self closing, and can't contain text, so you have to change it to

```
<input type="radio" value="" name="display" />Featured
```

Then add a class to DIV's so they are easier to target

```
<div id="Featured" class="desc" style="display:none">Featured desc</div>
```

Then you can do something like this

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    $('.desc').hide();
    $('#' + $.trim(this.nextSibling.nodeValue)).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p8D5Y/2/)

Comment: an answer as descriptive as the question.  Very nice.